# Raspberry Pi 4 disable automatic startup after power is provided

Tags: boot

I want to use my Raspi like a PC, meaning when I'm pressing the power button (PINS 5/6) it should startup. When pressing it again it should shutdown. This works as intended but when supplying my pi with power for the first time it always starts booting. How can I stop the autostartup and only wake it up from the halt state, when pressing the power button?

Answer (score 0):

The shutdown/startup function of GPIO3 **DOES NOT** work like a PC power button.
It does NOT power down - for the simple reason that the Pi has no power control circuitry.

All it does is halt the processor which continues to draw significant power.

Your Pi is working as designed.